# Javascript: What is the full purpose of this array splice?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm going through a Javascript course and its challenges. I don't have a question about how to do this particular challenge but I was going through the code in my mind to make sure I understood all of it and I ran into a question.

```
var strength = true;
var fear = false;
var pack = {
  foodPouch: ['carrot', 'mystery meat', 'apple', 42],
  addFood: function(foodItem) {
    this.foodPouch = this.foodPouch || [];
    this.foodPouch.push(foodItem);
  },
  gobbleFood: function(foodItem) {
    return(this.foodPouch.indexOf(foodItem) >= 0) ?
    this.foodPouch.splice(this.foodPouch.indexOf(foodItem), 1)[0] :
    alert('Your pack lacks ' + foodItem);
  },
  feedBird: function(birdFood) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.foodPouch.length; i++) {
      if (this.foodPouch[i] == birdFood) {
        alert('Feed beggar bird ' + this.foodPouch[i]);
      }
    }
  }
};

pack.feedBird('42');
```

My question is with this line:

```
return(this.foodPouch.indexOf(foodItem) >= 0) ?
        this.foodPouch.splice(this.foodPouch.indexOf(foodItem), 1)[0] :
        alert('Your pack lacks ' + foodItem);
```

Why does the first ternary action that splices the array end with [0], which I believe makes that whole action into the value of the spliced array? I can see if you wanted to declare it as some kind of variable, but it seems like the main purpose is just to splice it off. Does it matter if that [0] is there at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return(this.foodPouch.indexOf(foodItem) >= 0) ?
        this.foodPouch.splice(this.foodPouch.indexOf(foodItem), 1)[0] :
        alert('Your pack lacks ' + foodItem);
```

This statement translated to English says:

Return "the zeroth element of the 'returned array' after removing the `foodItem`" if it exists there. Or just display a message if it is not.

Or I can write it in this manner in JS:

```
if (this.foodPouch.indexOf(foodItem) >= 0) {
    var removedItems = this.foodPouch.splice(this.foodPouch.indexOf(foodItem), 1);
    return removedItems[0]; 
};
else
    alert('Your pack lacks ' + foodItem);
```

Comment: Im curious, is alert(something); the same as return alert(something);?

Comment: alert() actually doesn't return anything. When placed in front of return the function therefore returns "undefined".

So, in the above question if the foodItem is there the function returns the removed item and if not doesn't return anything.

Comment: Makes sense, I was too lazy to try it. Im going to delete my answer as they are all the same and yours is more complete. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) removes elements from an array, then returns an array containing the removed elements.

In this case, the `gobbleFood` function is checking for the presence of a particular item (using `indexOf`) and is removing and returning the first instance of it if it exists in `foodPouch`.

The removal is done using `splice`, and since `splice` returns an array of items removed, even if it's only removed 1 item as in this case, it's necessary to use `[0]` as an indexer to get at the single item that was removed.